# Rubocop.yml excludes being ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rubocop

My excludes are being ignored.

## .rubocop.yml

```
Rails:
  Enabled: true
  Exclude:
    - 'db/**/*'
    - 'config/**/*'
    - 'script/**/*'
    - 'bin/{rails,rake}'
    - 'vendor/**/*'
    - 'spec/fixtures/**/*'
    - 'tmp/**/*'
```

Rubocop Message:

> config/environments/development.rb:3:1: C: Metrics/BlockLength: Block
>   has too many lines. [32/25] Rails.application.configure do ...
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ config/environments/production.rb:3:1:
>   C: Metrics/BlockLength: Block has too many lines. [29/25]
>   Rails.application.configure do ...

## pre-commit GitHook

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'english'
require 'rubocop'

ADDED_OR_MODIFIED = /A|AM|^M/.freeze

changed_files = `git status --porcelain`.split(/\n/).
    select { |file_name_with_status|
      file_name_with_status =~ ADDED_OR_MODIFIED
    }.
    map { |file_name_with_status|
      file_name_with_status.split(' ')[1]
    }.
    select { |file_name|
      File.extname(file_name) == '.rb'
    }.join(' ')

system("rubocop --force-exclusion -a #{changed_files}") unless changed_files.empty?

status=$CHILD_STATUS.to_s[-1].to_i

if status == 0 
  system("echo -en '\\033[32mFormatting Passed, Committing...\\033[0;39m\n'")
  exit 0
else
  system("echo -en '\\033[1;31mCannot commit, formating failing. Use --no-verify to force commit.\\033[0;39m\n'")
  exit 1
end
```

Comment: Please provide feedback if you vote down. this is a valid issue, and code is shown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your configuration file only defines excludes for the `Rails` department of cops, so it is correct that `BlockLength`, which is in the `Metrics` department, still inspects the files.

If what you meant to do was to ignore these files for all cops, you can use:

```
AllCops:
  Exclude:
    - 'db/**/*'
    - 'config/**/*'
    - 'script/**/*'
    - 'bin/{rails,rake}'
    - 'vendor/**/*'
    - 'spec/fixtures/**/*'
    - 'tmp/**/*'

Rails:
  Enabled: true
```

Or if you just want to exclude the files for the `Metrics` cops, substitute `AllCops` for `Metrics` in the configuration above.