How to exclude all Metrics cops from a group of files in rubocop
Given that a configuration like this:
# .rubocop.yml

Metrics:
  Exclude:
    - Gemfile
    - config/**/*.rb
    - spec/factories/*.rb
    - db/migrate/*.rb


does not seem to work:
$ bundle exec rubocop Gemfile

Inspecting 1 file
C

Offenses:

Gemfile:152:1: C: Metrics/BlockLength: Block has too many lines. [31/25]
group :development do ...
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

1 file inspected, 1 offense detected


What would be the right way to disable the Metrics cops on these files?
Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55860235/3701149 , but perhaps no longer works?
